# Problema com LEFT JOIN no PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, amigos.

Tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco mysqli para registrar o acesso a determinado local:

1. visitante, cujos dados sempre serão preenchidos.
2. corporativo, cujos dados serão preenchidos apenas se o visitante representar uma empresa.
3. veiculo, cujos dados serão preenchidos se o visitante vier de carro.

Ao fazer uma busca para retornar todos os resultados, utilizo a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `visitante` 
LEFT JOIN `corporativo` ON `corporativo`.`id_visitante` = `visitante`.`id_visitante` 
LEFT JOIN `veiculo` ON `veiculo`.`id_visitante` = `visitante`.`id_visitante` 
WHERE `visitante`.`entrada` LIKE '%$data%' OR `visitante`.`status` LIKE '%Aberto%' 
GROUP BY `visitante`.`id_visitante` 
ORDER BY `visitante`.`entrada`;
```

O que acontece é que nos registros onde não tenho dados do visitante corporativo ou dados do veículo, ele retorna minha id.visitante como NULL.

Acho que é algum problema do PHP pois ao fazer essa query no phpmyadmin, ele retorna todos os dados normalmente.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão???

Obrigado.

Comment: pelo formato da sua query parece que você não está usando [Prepared Statements] (https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Talvez seja algum valor em `$data` que está causando o problema?

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida, realmente desconheço esses preparativos. Entretanto tinha problema com essa query no sistema que fiz na mão e agora estou aprendendo um pouco de CodeIgniter e estou reconstruindo o mesmo no CI. Acredito que as funções do CI já incorporem estes procedimentos.
Entretanto, retirei todas as condições e só deixei o left join para as outras tabelas e mesmo assim quando não tenho os registros dessas tabelas, minha id retorna nulo. Quando as outras tabelas estão preenchidas, o id vem normal.

Comment: Se eu fizer a mesma query dando um select visitante.id_visitante, todos os resultados vem normal. Apenas quando eu dou um select * que tenho o problema.

Comment: São 3 id_visitante diferentes, os da tabela não correspondente vem nulos mesmo. tem certeza que está olhando o correto? Seria bom tirar aquele * da query e usar os campos corretamente no formato SELECT tabela.campo ou SELECT alias.campo, ....

Comment: São muitos campos. Mas realmente o problema era o nome. Eu simplesmente mudei o nome no banco de dados para visitante_id e isso me retornou corretamente. Não sei pq a consulta não me retorna o que eu quero, mesmo dizendo que era visitante.id_visitante. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente criar aliases para a coluna id na tabela visitante, ou então mudar o nome. Se nas tabelas envolvidas existem várias colunas com o mesmo nome (id_visitante) ele pode estar 'escolhendo' as últimas (corporativo.id_visitane, veiculo.id_visitante) que de fato estão vazias e acabam sobrescrevendo o valor da primeira (visitante.id_visitante).

Lembre-se que você não precisa trazer três vezes o valor do id_visitante

O ideal seria algo assim:
(Apenas um exemplo)

```
SELECT 
    visitante.id as id_visitante
    , visitante.nome
    , corpoartivo.empresa
    , veiculo.placa
FROM
    visitante 
    LEFT JOIN corporativo ON corporativo.id_visitante = visitante.id
    LEFT JOIN veiculo ON veiculo.id_visitante = visitante.id
```

Comment: Realmente era o nome que estava dando conflito. Não sei pq a consulta não retorna o id correto, mesmo dizendo que eu quero da tabela visitante.
Eu mudei o nome da id como chave estrangeira nas outras tabelas e me retornou corretamente agora. Mto obrigado.